# How does StumbleUpon store their categories in their Database?

Tags: database, database-design

Each user have their own set of chosen categories, then only those chosen categories will be shown to the user when they stumble from site to site.

So, my question is this a one to many relationship? Like one user id is connected to many categories in the database?

Then all the categories is stored in one table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used StumbleUpon, but here is my guess:

They have a `User` table, a `Category` table, and a `FavoriteCategory` table.

The `Category` table has an `id` column and a `name` column. The `User` table has an `id` column, an `email` column, a `username` column, etc.

The `FavoriteCategory` table is where the magic happens!

It has a `userId` column and a `categoryId` column. Every time a user adds a new favorite category, a new record is added to the `FavoriteCategory` table with the user's `id` as the `userId` and the category's `id` as the `categoryId`. All it takes is a simple `INNER JOIN` to grab all the data in a single query.

With this schema, users can have an unlimited number of favorite categories! :]

Edit: Try reading about [third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).